# Using SED to remove text between X= and a space unexpected behavior

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'm trying to remove "var1=test1 " from "123 var1=test1 var2=test2 456"

For some reason, the result also removes var2=test2... Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

> echo 123 var1=test1 var2=test2 456 | sed "s/var1=.* //g"

The result is:
123 456

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `/.* /` captures everything up to and including the *last* space.  Instead, try

```
sed "s/var1=[^ ]*//g"
```

To remove everything after the `=` that is *not* a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '123 var1=test1 var2=test2 456' | sed -r 's/var1=\S+ //g'
```

Your mistake is using the greedy `.*` that is matching untill the last space. Instead, I search for *non space* `\S`

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because .* is greedy. Since the first space should end it, use:

```
s/var1=[^ ]* //g
```

You probably want to put that one in single quotes in case your shell wants to do something to the ^